# Why is the CSS attribute for 'text' block in the below code not being applied?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I am trying to create `div` elements through Javascript, and add attributes to them through CSS.

There are two attributes:

1. One for the background. This is working fine.
2. One is for text. I am trying to add attributes to it in the say way I am adding attributes to the background, through id of the created `div` element. But due to some reason "TEXT" is not being displayed.

I have narrowed down the problem to `diva.id="text";`. But I am not sure what is wrong with it.

```js
//grey block
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.id="overlay";
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";

//text
var diva=document.createElement('div');
diva.id="text";
var text= document.createTextNode('TEXT');
diva.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(diva);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: why don't you simply add the style property in the object, before appending it to the body?

Comment: @Carles I have tried that. But I am interested in knowing what is wrong with the above code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the elements overlap, and you have `z-index: 2` on the `#overlay` element, which means it's closer to the viewer than the default would be. But the other one is at the default distance. Since the `#overlay` is not transparent, it completely hides the `#text` element.

Here you can see what happens if I add `z-index: 2` to `#text`, just by way of example:

```js
//grey block
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.id="overlay";
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";

//text
var diva=document.createElement('div');
diva.id="text";
var text= document.createTextNode('TEXT');
diva.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(diva);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Battling `z-index`s usually isn't what you want, though (although sometimes it is). You may want to structure things differently so the two elements default to the same layer or similar.